# How to merge multiple dataframes of different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge multiple dataframe by a common column such that all the non matching data has NA.

```
D1:                             D2:
    ID  val1  val2                  ID   Target   
    1    x     y                    1      0
    1    x     y                    1      1
    1    a     b
    1    a     c

 D3:                             D4:
    ID  random  new                  ID   Targetnew  
    1    x     y                    1      1       
    1    x     y                    1      0      
    1    a     b
    1    a     c
So the merge will become 

  ID  val1  val2 Target  Targetnew random new 
    1    x     y     0   1          x      y
    1    x     y     1   0          x      y
    1    a     b     NA  NA         a      b
    1    a     c     NA  NA         a      c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
df1 = D1.merge(D2, how='left', on='ID')
df2 = D3.merge(D4, how='left', on='ID')
```

then merge `df1` and `df2`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat()` and remove multiple duplicated columns:

```
df = pd.concat([D1, D2, D4, D3], axis="columns")
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

```
>>> df
   ID val1 val2  Target  Targetnew random new
0   1    x    y     0.0        1.0      x   y
1   1    x    y     1.0        0.0      x   y
2   1    a    b     NaN        NaN      a   b
3   1    a    c     NaN        NaN      a   c
```